# How to drive 20 monitors from one Mac Pro

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors

I am researching for a project what would require 20 monitors to be driven from (ideally) a single Mac Pro.  The only solutions i have seen and are familiar with are geared towards 2-4 monitors from a single machine.  Is this even possible?

Comment: All 20 monitors displaying different content, or are some/all of them mirrored ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [Video Distribution Amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_amplifier).

I believe a [DVI splitter like this](http://www.kvmstuff.com/smartavi-8-port-dvi-video-splitter-dvs8p.html) can be daisy-chained.

There are HDMI splitters too. [This one is nice](http://www.octavainc.com/HDMI%20Ethernet%20matrix%20switch%204x8.html) because the signal can be transmitted over CAT 5/6 Ethernet cables. Not sure if it's cascade-able though. Here's [a 3x8 HDMI switch splitter](http://www.octavainc.com/HDMI%20switch%20splitter_3x8.html) which specifically states it can cascade signals, so you just daisy-chain them together. You'll need three. :)

**EDIT:** A little more googling, found [this 1:10 HDMI VDA](http://www.gefen.com/kvm/dproduct.jsp?prod_id=5023). You only need two of those!

I hope you have a lot of money for this project. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your solution but LG has a [network monitor solution.](http://networkmonitor.lge.com/us/technology/index.jsp) This allows for a single PC to be shared by up to 11 users at the same time.

[image]

I haven't tried this out myself but I have seen it in action at a computer showroom dealing in LG products. So if you need different content on your monitors, this should work. This technology is called **Desktop Virtualization**.

Comment: I get the impression that he's trying to display onto 20 monitors from the same computer, not have 20 terminals using one computer remotely.

Comment: @nhinkle - exactly.. that's why I wasn't sure if this would work out for him, but it came to mind as I had looked at this recently and thought maybe it could help if he needed different content to be displayed on different monitors. Though the answer is totally based on an assumption of an incomplete question.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense then.